# null value in getIntent.getExtras.getString()

Tags: android, android-intent

This is my code in my first activity:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, OtherScreen.class);
    i.putExtra("id1", "first");
    i.putExtra("id2", "second");
    startActivity(i);
```

where first,second are the values I want to be passed.
and on my other class i have this:

```
Intent i = getIntent();
        Bundle extras = i.getExtras();
        String result = extras.getString("id1");
        System.out.println("yeah"+result);
```

but after i run it, my result is null.Can you help me?
If I write my getString in that ways, I am getting syntax errors.

```
String result = extras.getString(id1); //id1 cannot be resolved to a variable
String result = extras.getString("id1","default value"); // remove argument
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Intent i = new Intent(yourcurrentactivity.this, OtherScreen.class);

i.putExtra("id1", "first");
i.putExtra("id2", "second");
startActivity(i);

Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
    String result = extras.getString("id1");                
    System.out.println("yeah"+result);
}
```

Comment: i have to two values one is getting and other one is null

Comment: @Prasad What? I guess the possibility that another value is null because 1)key name is mismatch 2) null before sent through i.putExtra -- you should debug to check and make sure that the value is not be null before you do i.putExtra...

Comment: @smith i got that one issue in the second one u told about null before passing

Comment: I have the same problem here is my code in the first activity:
     `Intent i = new Intent(RecordsHistory.this,RecordHistory.class);
  i.putExtra("page_title","***");
  i.putExtra("page", page);
  i.putExtra("date", dt);
  i.putExtra("id", id);
  startActivity(i);`
and in the second one is
     `Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
  page_id    = bundle.getInt("page");
  int row_id = bundle.getInt("id");
  String page_title = bundle.getString("page_title");
  Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), page_title+", "+page_id+", "+row_id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`

but page title is null

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively for more accuracy, you can use

```
`if(getIntent.hasExtras("id11")'
```

before actually getting extras from the bundle and do some action if its  null

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
getIntent().getStringExtra("id11");
```

Of course its best to FIRST check if it even has the extra before you even go for it.

Ref:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getStringExtra(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem in my project.

```
intent.putExtra("key",editText.getText())
```

I have changed editText.getText() to String text.

```
String text = editText.getText();
intent.putExtra("key",text);
```

And that has solved my problem. Seems like it is an API problem.

Answer (score 0):

You may try :`String result = extras.get("id1");`

Answer (score 0):

I was also having trouble with null values. @YuDroid's suggestion to use `if (getIntent.hasExtras("id11")` is a good idea. Another safety check that I found when reading the [Bundle documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/BaseBundle.html#getString%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29), though, is

```
getString(String key, String defaultValue)
```

That way if the string does not exist you can provide it with a default value rather than it being returned null.

So here is @AprilSmith's answer modified with the default String value.

```
Intent i = new Intent(yourcurrentactivity.this, OtherScreen.class);

i.putExtra("id1", "first");
i.putExtra("id2", "second");
startActivity(i);

Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
    String result = extras.getString("id1", "myDefaultString"); // This line modified
    System.out.println("yeah"+result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If anybody still having this issue..here is the solution

the datatype you are passing in first activity should be same in receiving end.

```
'Intent myIntent = new Intent(D1Activity.this, D2Activity.class);'
        'myIntent.putExtra("dval", dval);'
       ' D1Activity.this.startActivity(myIntent);'
```

in D2Activity

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {;
        edval = extras.getInt ( "dval" );
    }
```

here extras.getString() will not work as we passed an Int not a string