# null value in getIntent.getExtras.getString()

Tags: android, android-intent

Hi i am trying to send  2 strings to another activity but i am getting the null exception error here is my code on first activity:

```
Intent zistactivity = new Intent(reshte.this,List1.class);  
zistactivity.putExtra("url","http://api.safshari.com/test.json");
zistactivity.putExtra("daste", "zist");
startActivity(zistactivity);
```

and my second activity is :

```
String url = getIntent().getExtras().getString("url");
String daste = getIntent().getExtras().getString("daste");
```

and the logcat :

```
06-26 13:36:20.323: E/AndroidRuntime(597): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-26 13:36:20.323: E/AndroidRuntime(597): Process: com.safshari.konkor, PID: 597
06-26 13:36:20.323: E/AndroidRuntime(597): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.safshari.konkor/com.safshari.konkor.List1}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.os.Bundle android.content.Intent.getExtras()' on a null object reference
06-26 13:36:20.323: E/AndroidRuntime(597):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2236)
06-26 13:36:20.323: E/AndroidRuntime(597):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
06-26 13:36:20.323: E/AndroidRuntime(597):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
06-26 13:36:20.323: E/AndroidRuntime(597):  at  android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
06-26 13:36:20.323: E/AndroidRuntime(597):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
06-26 13:36:20.323: E/AndroidRuntime(597):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
06-26 13:36:20.323: E/AndroidRuntime(597):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
06-26 13:36:20.323: E/AndroidRuntime(597):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
06-26 13:36:20.323: E/AndroidRuntime(597):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
06-26 13:36:20.323: E/AndroidRuntime(597):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
06-26 13:36:20.323: E/AndroidRuntime(597):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
06-26 13:36:20.323: E/AndroidRuntime(597): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.os.Bundle android.content.Intent.getExtras()' on a null object reference
06-26 13:36:20.323: E/AndroidRuntime(597):  at com.safshari.konkor.List1.<init>(List1.java:32)
06-26 13:36:20.323: E/AndroidRuntime(597):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
06-26 13:36:20.323: E/AndroidRuntime(597):  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1606)
06-26 13:36:20.323: E/AndroidRuntime(597):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1066)
06-26 13:36:20.323: E/AndroidRuntime(597):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2226)
```

Comment: Add the exception message too

Comment: Can you post the 2 Activities here?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8822553/null-value-in-getintent-getextras-getstring?rq=1

Comment: @Soheyl Please check above link . I hope it will helps you .

Comment: @IITAmiya im getting same error my friend

Comment: show your manifest code please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the sender activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(reshte.this,List1.class);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("key1","value1");
(...)
intent.putExtras(bundle);
// Launch intent
```

In the receiver activity:

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
String value1 = bundle.getString("key1");
```

Try that. You must put all your passing data into a bundle, for better experience (at least, in my opinion)

Answer (score 0):

Check your manifest file if the two Activities are declared. Referring to the logs:

```
06-26 13:36:20.323: E/AndroidRuntime(597): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.safshari.konkor/com.safshari.konkor.List1}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.os.Bundle android.content.Intent.getExtras()' on a null object reference
```

Answer (score 0):

You are sending the string value using Intent instead of in Bundle. so get value from Intent using getStringExtra:

```
 Intent intent=this.getIntent();
    if(intent !=null)
     value = intent.getStringExtra("variable");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are putting extra directly, use get(Type)Extra instead.

Answer (score -1):

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
String url= bundle.getString("url");

//bundle contain all String data
```

Comment: I'm no Java programmer, but `String url = getIntent().getExtras().getString("url");` seems to be no different to what you posted above without any comment.