# Intent bundle / extras invoking NullPointerException

Tags: java, android

sorry in advance if I come across annoyed at this point! I've been trying for multiple hours to fix this :)

So, I really don't understand java NPEs. I should be getting the intent extras and I don't.

In MainActivity.java

```java
...
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,scriptViewer.class);
i.putExtra("script_name",script_name)
startActivity(i)
```

So far, it is ok, no?

```java
Intent j = getIntent();
String script_name = j.getExtras().getString("script_name");
```

The program has problems with this -

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.os.Bundle android.content.Intent.getExtras()' on a null object reference
```

++ Trust me, I've looked for ages, but nothing has seemed to work - TIA

Comment: `i.getExtras()` or `j.getExtras()` ?

Comment: If you don't understand NPEs I would strongly recommend [you read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it) for future debugging.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti i changed it. It was just a typo on this post only.

Comment: @MihirKekkar that answer involves Integer and not String.

Comment: @HenryHudson In your code `j` is `null`.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti I don't understand - I recieved the Intent...

Comment: You might consider editing your question and posting the entire class that contains the code that is failing. Depending on where those lines reside, they may or may not work.

Comment: Please take a look at here. It seems the same problem.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31069017/null-value-in-getintent-getextras-getstring

Comment: Please take a look at here. It seems the same problem. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31069017/null-value-in-getintent-getextras-getstring]

Comment: @SumanDash thanks, but I've added that code in perfectly and still doesnt work...-

Comment: Please post the code for scriptViewer.java (should be ScriptViewer btw) and your AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: @HenryHudson the linked question on NPEs uses the `Integer` class as an example, you can replace the `Integer` variable and initialization with a `String` variable and initialization and the actual reasoning behind the NPE would still apply (the fact that NPEs stem from reference variables containing null values).